# boost::asio::steady_timer doesn't work in boost::dll

Tags: c++, boost, dll, boost-asio

The boost::asio::steady_timer is working fine when it is started in the executable. By starting the steady_timer in the DLL, the timer expires immediately. What's wrong in my code? Is it a bug in boost::asio?

**api.h:**

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class my_api {
public:
   virtual void startTimer(boost::asio::io_service& ioservice) = 0;
   virtual ~my_api() {};
};
```

**Dll.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/dll.hpp>
#include "api.h"

class my_plugin : public my_api {
public:
   void startTimer(boost::asio::io_service& ioservice) {
      std::cout << "start timer (15 sec)\n";
      boost::asio::steady_timer timer{ ioservice, std::chrono::seconds{ 15 } };
      timer.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &ec) { std::cout << "15 sec\n"; });
   };

    ~my_plugin() {};
};

static boost::shared_ptr<my_api> createPlugin() {
   return boost::shared_ptr<my_api>(new my_plugin());
}

BOOST_DLL_ALIAS(
   createPlugin,
   create_plugin
)
```

**Main.cpp:**

```
#include <boost/dll/import.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include "../DLL/api.h"

int main() {

   boost::asio::io_service ioservice;

   /* load dll */
   boost::filesystem::path shared_library_path("..\\Debug");
   shared_library_path /= "DLL";

   boost::function<boost::shared_ptr<my_api>()> creator = boost::dll::import_alias<boost::shared_ptr<my_api>()>(
      shared_library_path,
      "create_plugin",
      boost::dll::load_mode::append_decorations
   );
   boost::shared_ptr<my_api> plugin = creator();

   /* set timer 10 sec */
   std::cout << "start timer (10 sec)\n";
   boost::asio::steady_timer timer{ ioservice, std::chrono::seconds{ 10 } };
   timer.async_wait([](const boost::system::error_code &ec) { std::cout << "10 sec\n"; });

   /* create my_plugin in dll with timer 15 sec */
   plugin->startTimer(ioservice);

   ioservice.run();

   return 0;
}
```

**output:**

```
start timer (10 sec)
start timer (15 sec)
15 sec
10 sec
```

The 15 sec timer was called in the DLL and expires immediately. The 10 sec timer was called in the executable and works fine.

I'm working with Visual Studio 2017 V15.5.2.

Comment: Just use `wait` instead of `async_wait`?

Answer (score 1):

This is no bug, in your `startTimer` method you created `steady_timer` object and invoked `asyncWait` method, but this method returns immediately (see reference http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_waitable_timer/async_wait.html), so the timer object is deleted and handler is invoked (then 15 sec is printed). You should check value of `ec` variable, it may indicate that operation was aborted.

In main function timer object works, because program is waiting in this line

```
ioservice.run();
```

so handler can be invoked after 10 seconds.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are right: Timer started in dll was canceled. How can i create a timer in a dll that is handeld by ioservice in executeable?

Comment: I have never used boost dll, but if you want to call `async_wait` method, `timer` object should exist after calling `startTimer` method. Your class `my_plugin` can store members, so you can define `steady_timer` as member of `my_plugin` class, add construtor which takes `io_service` as parameter, and in constructor of `my_plugin` object `steady_timer` is initialized by `io_service`. Then in `startTimer` you can set expiry time and run `async_wait` method.

Comment: The problem was the deleted timer like you said. Now it works fine. Thank you very much!